# Visual studio installer rebuilds vdproj project file and conflicts with tfs

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, installation

I have a solution with multiple projects in them and I'm building some installers. I built a merge module for a common group of files that most of the projects work with to make building the installers easier. The solution is unfortunately under that laughably called source control, tfs.

The problem seems to be that when any of the installers build, the project file for the installers gets touched by the compiler. It either tries to delete and recreate it or at least edit it. TFS complains about this action and we get maybe up to 30 error popups. They say:

"The command you are attempting cannot be completed because the file [filename] is under source code control and not checked out."

If you click ok on all of them, everything builds just fine. And of course, if I checkout the installer project files each and every time I want to build, I don't get the popups. That's not a viable solution. I suppose I could change it so the installers do not get built each and every time someone tries to build the whole solution. Which technically, that's really the way I should have it configured. Or put the installers in their own solution. This would reduce the annoyance factor for every build, but that doesn't solve the overall problem. There has to be some configuration that builds everything without the popups. Or lack of that, the installers are always going to be in source control no matter what solution they are in and how frequently they get built. The above error must go or I must choose an alternative installer project type.

Comment: In case you are not already aware, [vdproj files are no longer supported in VS 2012](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winformssetup/threads).

Answer (score 0):

After searching around most of today, I found a thread located [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/650587/vs-2010-sp1-changes-packagecode-in-vdproj-on-each-build-but-fails-as-source-controlled) that seems to discuss the very problem I was having.

It seems Microsoft was able to create a hotfix. In this thread it references the below links to resolve the problem:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=35848

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/KB2529927